# How to make done button is active in modal sheet?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Example, Done is not active by enter

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using interface builder, you can create an outlet for the "Done" button and use `[myButton highlight:YES]`.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsbutton_Class/Reference/Reference.html), under the "highlight:" method, for doc reference

EDIT: To make the button respond to the "return" key, you can use `[myButton setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"]`.

Comment: Ok, it's highlighted but not active for example by enter

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think you can use ``[myButton setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"]`` to make it respond to enter key.

Comment: Yes! I just 1 minute ago did it! Thx